# How can I get my albums to sort by track numbers in iTunes 11's expanded view?

Tags: itunes, macos

I've been trying to figure out why my track sort order is wrong in iTunes 11. I have track metadata, and sorting by Album in the songs view works fine, but in the expanded view my tracks appear in what seems to be totally random order.

How can I get this to sort by track number within the album?

[image: example of the invalid track sort order]

Comment: Not sure on album view, but in song view, ordering is dependent on the path you take to get to that ordering. Sorting by track then album then artist gives a different final order than sorting by album then track then artist. I suspect this oddity will carry over into subsequent album view.

Answer (score 1):

I can make my iTunes show something similar, if I set some of the tracks in an album to a different Disk Number compared to the rest.

[image: Album with one track from a different disc]

Try selecting one of the out-of-order tracks, then use File > Get Info to open the window I've shown here.  Is there anything different about the information for the out-of-order tracks?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is really old now, but if anyone wants the answer on how to fix it, you go to song info -> sorting -> and you'll see the songs up the top have been sorted by song, album, artist, composer, etc whilst the ones below are not sorted like this. If you remove the "sort as" input they will come good.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! This was what was wrong with my files.